# Maximum String length when concatenating strings in Android studio

Tags: android, string, intellij-idea

I have come across an issue when concatenating strings in Android Studio. It appears that the maximum length is 120 characters but only when concatenating.

If I have this for example:

```
private static final String HOW_LONG_CAN_A_STRING_BE =
            "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "";

String test = HOW_LONG_CAN_A_STRING_BE;
```

When I hover over the String HOW_LONG_CAN_A_STRING_BE it resolves the concatenated string.

However if I add any more characters like in this example:

```
private static final String HOW_LONG_CAN_A_STRING_BE =
            "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "123456789A"
            + "1";

String test = HOW_LONG_CAN_A_STRING_BE;
```

When I hover over the HOW_LONG_CAN_A_STRING_BE it causes an error to appear in the Event Log of Android Studio with the following details:

```
"123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A12345 ...
": Incorrect expression ""123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A12345 ...
"".
com.intellij.util.IncorrectOperationException: Incorrect expression ""123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A123456789A12345 ...
"".
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiJavaParserFacadeImpl.createExpressionFromText(PsiJavaParserFacadeImpl.java:325)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiElementFactoryImpl.createExpressionFromText(PsiElementFactoryImpl.java:667)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.javadoc.JavaDocInfoGenerator.calcInitializerExpression(JavaDocInfoGenerator.java:613)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.javadoc.JavaDocInfoGenerator.appendInitializer(JavaDocInfoGenerator.java:661)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.javadoc.JavaDocInfoGenerator.generateFieldJavaDoc(JavaDocInfoGenerator.java:459)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.javadoc.JavaDocInfoGenerator.generateDocInfoCore(JavaDocInfoGenerator.java:231)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.javadoc.JavaDocInfoGenerator.generateDocInfo(JavaDocInfoGenerator.java:255)
    at com.intellij.lang.java.JavaDocumentationProvider.generateExternalJavadoc(JavaDocumentationProvider.java:512)
    at com.intellij.lang.java.JavaDocumentationProvider.generateDoc(JavaDocumentationProvider.java:500)
    at com.intellij.lang.documentation.CompositeDocumentationProvider.generateDoc(CompositeDocumentationProvider.java:138)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.documentation.DocumentationManager$9$4.compute(DocumentationManager.java:665)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.documentation.DocumentationManager$9$4.compute(DocumentationManager.java:660)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.documentation.DocumentationManager$9.getDocumentation(DocumentationManager.java:659)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.documentation.DocumentationManager$10.run(DocumentationManager.java:763)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$RunnableConsumer.consume(QueueProcessor.java:298)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$RunnableConsumer.consume(QueueProcessor.java:295)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2$1.run(QueueProcessor.java:110)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2.consume(QueueProcessor.java:107)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2.consume(QueueProcessor.java:104)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$3$1.run(QueueProcessor.java:215)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$3.run(QueueProcessor.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

This is a problem because I am trying to create a database and the String that holds the database create statement is greater than 120 characters. Has anybody come across this issue before and if so how do I get around it without having to make my column names unreadable?

Here is the create statement that fails:

```
CREATE TABLE reminder(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  createdAt TEXT, 
  startDate TEXT, 
  endDate TEXT, 
  reminder_time INTEGER, 
  repeats INTEGER, 
  deferTime INTEGER, 
  alarmOn INTEGER, 
  reminderOn INTEGER, 
  description TEXT
)
```

Comment: Is this only an issue when hovering over the variable?

Comment: Through my initial testing it didn't seem to matter when I ran the code. It must just be an android studio or intellij-idea issue. I will have to keep an eye on it.

Comment: This issue seems to have been resolved with updating to Android Studio Version 0.61

Comment: In general, IDE internal errors usually do not have anything to do with your code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed up after the comment by Artjom B and found that it didn't affect the creation of the database.

I recently updated to Android Studio version 0.61 and the problem no longer seems to exist.